# Profit and loss with cost to carry report: Preference to show / not show symbol level information

Tags: mysql, report, ssrs-2012, rdl

We need the below enhancement in the "Profit and Loss Cost to Carry" Report

- Right now when we group this report by selecting any parameter say Account, Asset, Custom UDA 1, etc then automatically Symbol level information also comes.
- But here we need to give the preference. This will be on the front end.

Preference Name: "Show Symbol Info in Grouping": with 2 options True and False.

If True (Default Value): Report will work in the existing way. Means if we select any grouping then automatically Symbol Level information will also come.

If False: In this case just the Summary row will come (not any Symbol Level information)

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not the most efficient way to solve this. You could just add a report parameter and set the hidden property of the rowgroup that show the Symbol level data.

So add a new parameter called say `pShowSymbols` with two options e.g.

```
Value Label
0     Show Symbols
1     Hide Symbols
```

Set the default value to 0

Then set the hidden property of the rowgroup that show the Symbol level data to something like

```
=Parameters!pShowSymbols.Value = 1
```

This will return `true` when "Hide Symbols" is selected by the user and the rowgroup will not be shown.